# how to pass value to pop up window using javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I want to open new window from existing form.When I am clicking on new window in form then new form should open with results of value entered,but new window form is opening with main page,not able to get text box value from parent form.

How to call textfield input value in popup window from parent window using javascript?

```
//currently I'm using following code:
<script type="text/javascript">
function pop_up5() {
  var l_url=window.opener.document.getElementById("name").value;
  window.open(l_url,'''','scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=550,height=400');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing querystring fields..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your text field's id is `myTextField`, whatever you named it. if it has no id, set a id for it. then, in the popup window, you can use JavaScript `parent.document.getElementById('myTextField').value` to get the value of the textfield.

Comment: @muthun kumaran: now the problem is in eclipse i can able to store the child window values in database but in chrome and firefox nt able to store those values??

Comment: can not understand your problem, do you mean the code doesn't work in chrome or firefox? i'm sorry, i made a mistake. should use window.opener instead of parent. so the code will be window.opener.document.getElementById('myTextField').value

Answer (score 2):

Assign `window.open()` to a variable so you can access it's elements.

```
<form>
    <input type="textbox" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Open window" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    var myWindow = window.open();
    myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('txt').value;
};
</script>
```