# Passing a value from a popup to the main form

Tags: asp.net

I have a popup with a gridview on it and I would like to populate a textbox on the parent form with the text from the selected row/column. The code I am using below works but it refreshes the popup window with the parent form and populates the textbox in the popup. Is there way that when "Select" is pressed it closes the popup and adds the text to the textbox on the parent form?

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID, ProductCode, Item, RetailCost" HeaderText="Select"
 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Default.aspx?ID={0}&ProductCode={1}&Item={2}&RetailCost={3}"
 Text="Select" />

 ProductTextBox.Text = Request.QueryString("Item")
```

Comment: are you using jQuery lightbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass value to pop up window using javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967099/how-to-pass-value-to-pop-up-window-using-javascript-function)

Comment: no I am not using lightbox? I cant seem to get the popup to close and fill in the data on the parent form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fire a Javascript method in your parent window from your popup window.

So for example, in your parent window create a function that you want to call from your child popup:

```
function FillTextFromPopup(text){
      // populate your text here...
}
```

You can call now call this function from your child popup window, and also close your popup by adding some code like this to your button:

```
onClick="window.opener.FillTextFromPopup('yourTextString'); window.close();"
```

Using this method, rather than directly accessing the textbox on the parent, such as `window.opener.document.getElementById('yourTextBox')` is also cleaner as any changes you make to the parents textbox's and possible ID's don't have to be carried through to the child popup too.

Comment: I will try this, I have an issue were the popup wont close when I hit the x. I think this is because I have it when the textbox has focus the popup loads and wont close unless I minimize the popup.